# Assume $X$ is countably infite and $Y$ is finite, show that $X \cup Y$ is countably infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

So in general I'm stuck with this question and I looked at the solutions and they defined a bijection between $\mathbb{N_0}$ and $X \cup Y$  that I don't understand. Let me first quickly build the proof.

Notation : $E_{n}= \{ j \in \mathbb{Z}| 1 \leq j \leq n \} $

So we know that $Y \backslash X \subset Y$, then this is a finite set, so there exists a bijection $f:E_{n} \to Y\backslash X$. Another bijection $g: \mathbb{N_0} \to X$ exists because $X$ is countably infite.

Define the function $h: \mathbb{N_0}\to X \cup Y$:
$h(k) = g(k)$ if $k \leq n$
$h(k) = f(k-n)$ if $k >n$.

I think $n$ is the cardinality of the set $Y$. But I don't understand this bijection. Assume that $n = 16$, then what happens with $k = 33$? There is no $17th$ element in $E_{n}$ so i'm kinda confused about this part. Can someone clarify?

They then conclude that $h$ is a bijection because $f$ and $g$ are bijections and because $X \backslash Y$ and $X$ are disjunct. This reasoning I also don't understand, but I think my main problem is that I don't understand the function $h$.

Comment: I think the partial definitions of $h(n)$ should be swapped: it should be $h(k) = f(k)$ for $k \leq n$ and $h(k) = g(k-n)$ for $k > n$.

Comment: Are you sure $E_n$ is correct? Because for integers $n\geq 2$, the set $E_n$ by your definitions will be empty...

Comment: @5xum this is the definition in my textbook. Let's say n = 3, than $E_{n}$ = {1,2,3}. I'm sorry, I used the wrong inequalities, now it should be correct.

Comment: @MatyMangoo This sound more reasonable. But I'm in doubt, maybe this is the correct solution and I miss the point?

Comment: To understand the bijection visually, imagine two infinite columns of dots (representing $\mathbb{N}$) standing next to each other as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vdots &&\vdots\\
 \bullet &\hspace{25pt}& \bullet\\
 \bullet &&\bullet\\
\end{eqnarray*}
 The most natural bijection is to pair these two columns (means we have a bijection) horizontally. However, imagine your $Y$ has $n=16$ elements. What you do is, you take the $17$-th dot in the first column and map it to the $1$st dot in the second one (this means $h(17) = g(17-n) = g(1)$).. Then you map $18 \mapsto 2$, $19 \mapsto 3$, ...

Comment: @MatyMangoo Are you saying that the bijection they define is correct? Or that your suggestion is correct?

Comment: The bijection they define (after swapping $f$ with $g$ in the definition of $h$) is correct.

Comment: @MatyMangoo Then it is not correct :D

Comment: The first $16$ elements in the first column will be mapped bijectively to an additional set, which is $Y$ and has $16$ elements.

Comment: Induction on $n=|Y|$ should work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **all** your inequality signs are mixed up. For one, your definition of $E_n$ is

> $$E_{n}= \{ j \in \mathbb{Z}| 1 \geq j \geq n \}$$
> but under this condition, $E_n$ can only ever contain values smaller or equal to $1$. Also, you have $E_n=\emptyset$ for all $n\geq 2$, and in general, for negative values of $n\in\mathbb Z$, you have $|E_n| = 2+|n|= 2 - n$ which is just all the way confusing.

A more sensible definition would be

> $$E_{n}= \{ j \in \mathbb{Z}| 1 \leq j \leq n \}$$

because in this case, you have $|E_n| = n$ and you also have $E_n=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.

---

Also, the conditions of $k\leq n$ and $k>n$ should be flipped in your proof. As they are defined currently, the definition makes no sense, as you noticed yourself. But if you have

$$h(k)=\begin{cases}
g(k)&\text{if } if k>n\\
f(k-n)&\text{if } if l\leq n
\end{cases}$$

then it can be shown that $h$ is a bijection.

Comment: Okay, thanks, now I understand.

Comment: @user34 Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped. (Is it accept begging if I'm not the answerer?)

Comment: @stickynotememo It's not, but even if it were, I don't think accept begging is wrong. The "accept" mechanism is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think this proof is overcomplicated. Here is a simpler proposal.

The idea is the same of the famous Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel, i.e. you can make guests from $X$ go forward in the rooms enumeration so as to make room for new guests from $Y$.

Let $Y^{\prime}:=Y\setminus\{X\}$, then $X\cup Y=X\cup Y^{\prime}$.

Let $n:=|Y^{\prime}|\in \mathbb{N}$. $Y^{\prime}$ and $X$ are disjoint sets.

Now, let $\varphi:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection ($X$ is countably infinite). Then, we can show that the function $\widetilde{\varphi}(x)=\varphi(x)+n$ is a bijection between $X$ and $\mathbb{N}_{\geq n}$:

1. $\widetilde{\varphi}$ is injective. Assume $\widetilde{\varphi}(x)=\widetilde{\varphi}(y)$. It means $\varphi(x)+n=\varphi(y)+n$, which implies $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$, which implies $x=y$ since $\varphi$ is injective.
2. $\widetilde{\varphi}$ is surjective. Let $y\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq n}$. Then, $y$ can be written as $y=y^{\prime} + n$ for a certain $y^{\prime}\in \mathbb{N}$. Being $\varphi$ surjective, it exists $x\in X$ such that $\varphi(x)=y^{\prime}$. Then, adding $n$ to both sides, $\widetilde{\varphi}(x)=\varphi(x)+n=y^{\prime}+n=y$.

Now $|Y^{\prime}|=n$ means that there exists a bijection $\psi$ between $Y^{\prime}$ and $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Thus, we can define a function $f:X\cup Y^{\prime} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \ x \in Y^{\prime} \ f(x)=\psi(x)$, while $\forall \ x \in X \ f(x)= \widetilde{\varphi}(x)$ and this function is clearly a bijection.